# Mesh current method in finding currents

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image]

Can someone explain how to find the currents in the circuit? I am using mesh-current method but I don't know if I have to use twice \$R_2\$ and \$L_1\$ for each branch or not.

Comment: What do you mean twice R2 and L1? Perhaps sharing what equations you're looking at using might help more than hand waving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Take a look at the example circuit from here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesh_analysis)
[image]
from here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Mesh_Analysis_Example2_TeX.svg

Now take a look at the formulas for all 3 meshes:
[image]

If you ignore mesh 1, i.e. \$I_1 = 0\$ this circuit is similar to yours. You can see if the element that's part of both meshes shows up in both equations.